# Unable to send pdf file from bot to user in ms teams

Tags: node.js, botframework, microsoft-teams

NodeJS BotBuilder SDK version: 3.15.0
My code:

```
var pdf = {
  name: '<file_name>.pdf',
  contentType: 'application/pdf',
  contentUrl: '<https url to public pdf file>'
};
var reply = new builder.Message(session).addAttachment(pdf);
session.send(reply);
```

This code is the same in few online examples. The issue I have is that I always get error:

```
Error: POST to 'https://smba.trafficmanager.net/emea/v3/conversations/a%3A1TwHmhoGuZP2Mf9P0TTnjv8HkcaXzEHryv0sYCvDDUI-qrMitJtHRlAnIcedcDH_v3IfMBXtg_zo5MDVcS0-8hDCQ4sJzpJhrewBPK8uWJXYeShgmd-s7uh5o8kW4ebAP/activities/1543588440246' failed: [400] Bad Request
```

For image/png this code works fine.

What I want to achieve is this: (image is taken from Bot Framework Emulator) 
[File from the web sent from bot to user](https://i.stack.imgur.com/socx2.png)

The file is sent from bot without uploading it to users's one drive.
This works also when I tested the feature in test section of https://dev.botframework.com/bots. It doesn't work only in ms teams.

Comment: Did you have a look at the [Send and receive files through your bot](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/bots/bots-files) documentation? It looks like the flow on Microsoft Teams is different and you have to enable it in your manifest.

Comment: Yes, I did. I have enabled the flow in the manifest and did everything according to the documentation, and that part is perfectly fine. What I want to achieve is just to be able to send user a pdf file without having to ask for permission and to upload file to user's one drive. 
I will edit my post to explain a little better. @Mick

Answer (score 0):

The behaviour for sending files can differ per channel. Microsoft Teams doesn't support the direct upload method, like the WebChat / Emulator does. This is due to compliance reasons, [as Bill Bliss stated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53560046/unable-to-send-pdf-file-from-bot-to-user-in-ms-teams/53590414?noredirect=1#comment94061542_53590414).

> You can post messages with card attachments referencing existing SharePoint files using the Microsoft Graph APIs for OneDrive and SharePoint. Using the Graph APIs requires obtaining access to a user's OneDrive folder (for personal and groupchat files) or the files in a team's channels (for channel files) through the standard OAuth2 authorization flow. This method works in all Teams contexts.

Have a look at [Send and receive files through your bot](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/bots/bots-files)
 for the full documentation and how to implement.

---

An alternative option would be to use an AdaptiveCard where you can use an image thumbnail of the document combined with a button to directly download the PDF file from your public accessible URL.

Comment: BTW the reason for the limitation has nothing to do with built-in rendering of documents. It's because upload and download of documents to/from Office 365 is strictly controlled for compliance reasons.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, @BillBliss-MSFT!